# Change windows service name during runtime

Tags: c#, windows-services, wmi

I have some windows services that are manually created using installutil.
They have a non compile time specific name that is assigned during installation (e.g. MyTest1, MyTest2, ...).

When the service is started, the property "ServiceName" has its default value "Service1".
I can change this in the constructor to e.g. "MyTest1" so that the correct name is displayed in event log. This works fine.

Currently I'm reading the name from a command line parameter. I can also get the name from the process id using WMI:

```
string filter = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE ProcessId = {0}", Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);

ManagementObjectSearcher query = new ManagementObjectSearcher(filter);
ManagementObjectCollection services = query.Get();

string serviceName;

foreach (ManagementObject service in services)
{
    serviceName = service.GetPropertyValue("Name").ToString();
    break;
}
```

Unfortunatly this does not work in the constructor of the service as it is not yet registered.
Retrieving the name during OnStart() works, but it can not be assigned to "ServiceName" as the service is running.

Any suggestions on how to get and assign the name dynamically without using start parameter or cfg?